# How am I using the LIKE SQL operator incorrectly?

Tags: sql, vba

I am using VBA and trying to perform a SQL query to measure how many records exist where a certain column has a prefix of a given string. As I am debugging this process I am left very confused because it seems like there is very little room for error, but I'm still seeing strange behavior. `SELECT * FROM [Part Sales Header] WHERE [Quote No] LIKE 'sm82520A' ;` finds one record as I'd expect. However, if I change it to `SELECT * FROM [Part Sales Header] WHERE [Quote No] LIKE 'sm82520%' ;` 0 records are found. By my understanding % should find anything that comes after.

If it is useful, the rest of the VBA code that I am using looks like this:

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Part Sales Header] WHERE [Quote No] LIKE 'sm82520A' ;"
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
QuoteNoAmount = rst.RecordCount
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using MS Access, [the wildcard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-wildcards-in-queries-and-parameters-in-access-ec057a45-78b1-4d16-8c20-242cde582e0b) is `*`, so it would be

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Part Sales Header] WHERE [Quote No] LIKE 'sm82520A*' ;"
```